# How to find biggest variant in an enum in Rust?

Tags: memory, enums, rust

I'm trying to improve the performance of a rust program, which requires me to reduce the size of some large `enum`s. For example

```rust
enum EE {
    A, // 0
    B(i32), //4
    C(i64), // 8
    D(String), // 24
    E { // 16
        x: i64,
        y: i32,
    },
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<EE>()); // 32
}
```

prints `32`. But if I want to know the size of `EE::A`, I get a compile error

```rust
error[E0573]: expected type, found variant `EE::A`
  --> src/main.rs:14:40
   |
14 |     println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<EE::A>());
   |                                        ^^^^^
   |                                        |
   |                                        not a type
   |                                        help: try using the variant's enum: `crate::EE`

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `play_rust`.
```

Is there a way to find out which variant takes the most space?

Comment: "Is there a efficient way to get the size of each enum variant?" → All variants have the same size, the size of the corresponding enum.

Comment: @mcarton "All variants have the same size" which is decided by the size of variant that consumes most memory,if I can find that variant quickly,I can improve my enum  definition quickly.I want to ask how to find that variant quickly, sorry I don't express well.

Comment: @mcarton In the above example,`D(String)` require most memory size,which is 24,so the size of enum is (24 + 8) = 32.If I replace the `D(String)` by `D(Box<String>)`, size of the enum can be reduced to 16.It is a great benefit if rust can tell me `D(String)` use 24 bytes, which is the max one of all variants,so the enum size should be 32 bytes,if the size of `D(String)` can be reduced, the size of enum can be reduced,too.

Comment: @mcarton while you are technically correct, I think you're splitting hairs and it's quite clear what OP intended. There is even a Clippy lint for _"large size difference between variants on an enum"_, because there is a concept of the size of an enum and space utilisation of each variant.

Comment: Tangentially, in a case like the example, you may also use `Box<str>` which is mostly the same as `Box<String>` but only costs 16 bytes, so this whole enum would fit in 24 while avoiding the cost of double indirection. There is rarely a good reason to use `Box<String>`.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use a nightly compiler, you can now use `rustc`'s `-Zprint-type-sizes` flag to show the size of each variant. Be warned, it's a noisy flag! Using the code from your example gives:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS=-Zprint-type-sizes cargo +nightly build --release
[..]
print-type-size type: `EE`: 32 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
print-type-size     discriminant: 4 bytes
print-type-size     variant `D`: 28 bytes
print-type-size         padding: 4 bytes
print-type-size         field `.0`: 24 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
print-type-size     variant `C`: 12 bytes
print-type-size         padding: 4 bytes
print-type-size         field `.0`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
print-type-size     variant `E`: 12 bytes
print-type-size         field `.y`: 4 bytes
print-type-size         field `.x`: 8 bytes
print-type-size     variant `B`: 4 bytes
print-type-size         field `.0`: 4 bytes
print-type-size     variant `A`: 0 bytes
[..]
```

Where we can see `EE::A` is `0` bytes.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to get the size of just one variant of an `enum`. The best you can do is get the size of what the variant contains, as if it were a standalone struct:

```
    println!("sizeof EE::A: {}", std::mem::size_of::<()>());         // 0
    println!("sizeof EE::B: {}", std::mem::size_of::<i32>());        // 4
    println!("sizeof EE::C: {}", std::mem::size_of::<i64>());        // 8
    println!("sizeof EE::D: {}", std::mem::size_of::<String>());     // 24
    println!("sizeof EE::E: {}", std::mem::size_of::<(i64, i32)>()); // 16
```

Even this isn't especially useful because it includes padding bytes that may be used to store the tag; as you point out, the size of the `enum` can be reduced to 16 if `D` is shrunk to a single pointer, but you can't know that from looking at just the sizes. If `y` were instead defined as `i64`, the size of each variant would be the same, but the size of the `enum` would need to be 24. Alignment is another confounding factor that makes the size of an `enum` more complex than just "the size of the largest variant plus the tag".

Of course, this is all highly platform-dependent, and your code should not rely on any `enum` having a particular layout (unless you can guarantee it with a `#[repr]` annotation).

If you have a particular `enum` you're worried about, it's not difficult to get the size of each contained type. Clippy also has a lint for `enum`s with extreme size differences between variants. However, I don't recommend using size alone to make manual optimizations to `enum` layouts, or boxing things that are only a few pointers in size -- indirection suppresses other kinds of optimizations the compiler may be able to do. If you prioritize minimal space usage you may accidentally make your code much slower in the process.