# Can I limit the size of a Rust enum?

Tags: enums, rust, discriminated-union

I have an enum type in my Rust program of which some variants may contain inner data.

```
enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B(u64),
    C(SmallStruct),
    D(Box<LargeStruct>)
}
```

This enum is going to be stored tens of thousands of times and memory usage is an issue. I would like to avoid accidentally adding a very large variant for the enum. Is there a way that I can tell the compiler to limit the size of an enum instance in memory?

Comment: run clippy and it will tell you.

Comment: See also [How to find biggest variant in an enum in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58856828/155423); [Solutions to performance issues caused by large variant size of enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51200405/155423).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of Rust 1.57 you can use asserts in a const context, so this kind of check will work:

```
// assert that MyEnum is no larger than 16 bytes
const _ASSERT_SMALL: () = assert!(mem::size_of::<MyEnum>() <= 16);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd0efc40300a3c9a57038e6e0ab0c695)

Original answer follows for historical reference.

---

As noted in the other answer, you can use the `const_assert!` macro, but it *will* require an external crate, [`static_assertions`](https://crates.io/crates/static_assertions). If you're looking for a std-only solution and can live with the uglier error message when the assertion fails, you can use this:

```
#[deny(const_err)]
const fn const_assert(ok: bool) {
    0 - !ok as usize;
}

// assert that MyEnum is no larger than 16 bytes
const _ASSERT_SMALL: () = const_assert(mem::size_of::<MyEnum>() <= 16);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c34e9cf1647427d4cf8d84ba90ba0f2a)

You can read about this technique, along with ways to improve it, in [the article](https://nikolaivazquez.com/posts/programming/rust-static-assertions/) written by the author of the `static_assertions` crate.

EDIT: Link to original article is non-functional, [web archive version](https://web.archive.org/web/20190609064323/https://nikolaivazquez.com/posts/programming/rust-static-assertions/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`const_assert!`](https://docs.rs/static_assertions/1.1.0/static_assertions/macro.const_assert.html) and [`mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) to assert that your enum is less than or equal to a certain size.